# Standardization & terminology

Tags: discussion

Today I noticed an answer to a question which included this:

> It was [AdjP].

From time to time, I see answers to questions posed by beginning students which make use of an array of terms and abbreviations that must represent to them yet *another* language they now have to learn!

So, a suggestion: in the Help Center, a glossary of terms which answerers are encouraged to employ, and which questioners can consult. The result will be a more useful and searchable Q&A database. Won't it?

Note that I am not suggesting anything like DEAD's tag name glossary here. This question has more in common with [bytebuster's.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/37009)

Answer (score 8):

I am in entire sympathy with this concern. But there are difficulties.

English grammatical terminology is in crisis. The rapid and rapidly accelerating change which formal study of English has undergone in the last century has led to a vast proliferation of competing terminologies, and many of the most central terms have different meanings for different grammarians. This isn't just a matter of conflict between Ancients and Moderns, between the traditional Latin-based and contemporary linguistics-based analyses; it's also a matter of conflict between opposed contemporary schools. And this situation is exacerbated by the fact that few teachers of English (to either native or non-native speakers) are rigorously trained in any of these grammars; they pick up scraps and orts of terminology at third or fourth hand and use whatever addresses their immediate pedagogical needs.

The upshot is that no glossary is going to secure universal assent. The best you can hope for is something like the Linguistics Association of Great Britain's [*Grammatical terminology recommended by the LAGB for use in schools*](http://lagb-education.org/grammatical-terminology-for-schools), 2014. This document frankly acknowledges that it has to be

> an exercise in compromise: compromise between the needs of schools [...] and those of universities, and compromise among proponents of different approaches to grammar.

It has an entire page laying out **“controversial assumptions”** [my emphasis] about the meaning and treatment of key terms like *phrase*, *phrase classes*, *noun phrases*, *specifier*, *determiner*, *genitive*, *pronoun*, *clause*, *complement*, *tense*, *aspect*, *conjunction*—and individual entries still must discriminate carefully between rival understandings and uses. The article on *clause*, for instance, ends on the caveat that “in spite of its central role in grammar, the notion 'clause' is problematic in relation to other grammatical concepts”, and goes on for three paragraphs sketching some of these problems.

The entire document runs nearly 30,000 words—66 pages of 12-point TNR in the .pdf.

It's an admirable document; I don't think we can do any better. But would it meet our need? —and could our Answerers be brought to use it?

Comment: So we have people using different terminology for the same ideas, and people using the same terminology for different ideas.  Wonderful! :-)

Comment: @snailplane It makes for some interesting (but frustrating) conversations.

Comment: A person would have to be living in the depths of the Ituri to be unaware of the food fight in the world of English grammar. It pops up at ELU from time to time, and here too. My thought was to standardize on a few useful terms and abbreviations under a 72 point disclaimer distancing ourselves from the fracas. Our credo would be: "We have no dog in that fight. The following terms are used here to simplify instruction for beginning and moderately advanced learners. These terms are only _official_ on this site."

Comment: @P.E.Dant But we *are* the dogs in this fight! ... How are you going to "standardize" between, say, me and BillJ on what a *clause* is, when LAGB can't agree?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Now if we made up our *own* terminology . . . We could, for instance, call nouns 'P.E.' and verbs *Snail*.

Comment: Pistols at twenty paces? I would hope that a shared interest in furthering the needs of the learners might allow you and BillJ (for example) to compromise and say: _I hereby commit within the confines of this site to agree that the definition of "franisaw" is "a crobel modified by the anterior pedoble," and to represent it by the term **FrW.** My use of the term here does not reflect my actual position on the pedobility of the franisaw._

Comment: @StoneyB Yes! That's exactly the kind of thing I intended.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The devil lies in that "problematic in relation to other grammatical concepts”. The purpose of Theory is to lend coherence to the description of Praxis.

Comment: How's that working out so far? From here, it seems incoherence is the rule. If people really can't agree on what a pronoun is....

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'll send you a copy of *Squishy Syntax* when I write it.

Comment: @Araucaria You know more (i.e. something) about the political pressures on the document than I do. What I see, without that knowledge, is a Quixotic effort to extend linguistic understanding to the pseudo-professionals who might actually accomplish something with it--an effort which I have no doubt has foundered not so much on the necessary squishiness of the understanding as on the aversion of the pseudo-professionals to having their misunderstanding exposed. ...

Comment: ... me, I'm a Shavian, an Old Fabian: I acknowledge that every scholar is circumstantially implicated in the universal corruption. There's nowhere to stand outside it.

Comment: @Araucaria Of course it's a ragbag. Your profession is a ragbag, what else could it produce? (Don't take that personally--my own profession is one "for which there is no polite name".) Press down the path of "pure theory" (as it now stands) and you end up with the minimalist Ptolemies and their epicycles. ... And so to bed ...

Comment: **\*sigh\*** _So as through a glass, and darkly / The age long strife I see..._ Plainly, I ought to have affixed a _trigger warning_ to my question. You might have _warned_ me, @StoneyB .

Comment: Will it really be impossible to accomplish as simple a task as agreeing on an abbreviation for _adverbial prepositional phrase_ without precipitating a clash of the titans?

Comment: @P.E. I can't agree to an abbreviation for something that doesn't exist ;-)

Comment: An obvious corollary to my question, it appears, is how to put the interests of new students of English ahead of allegiances to the People's Front of Judea, Campaign for a Free Galilee, and the Judean Popular People's Front. When a tyro with an understanding only of subject and predicate asks a simple question, I wonder how much she benefits from a discursive colloquy on the fine points of nomenclature?

Comment: @P.E.Dant In my experience discussion of the fine points of nomenclature is mostly confined to Comments and rarely shows up in answers unless they're implied by the question, and only when it is apparent that quærents are confused by use of a specific term they've been taught. Me, I'm an adherent of the Red Benjamin Brigade and scorn all the imperialist cabals you name.

Comment: **Haro! Haro!**

Comment: @P.E.Dant Guernseyman?

Comment: Tuchman somewhere calls it "an obscure call to arms." Old French or Norman etymology. Cited as [Flemish, too.](https://books.google.com/books?id=A5SBsr27sv0C&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%22Haro!%22+shouted+by+mob&source=bl&ots=-pr2yNn-xQ&sig=jM8ZOIW8kqv9-1f4kXyaKITWx-4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim_8SEqefOAhVCJiYKHZeqBckQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Haro!%22%20shouted%20by%20mob&f=false) Guernsey's not far off.

Comment: I found a good one [**here!**](https://books.google.com/books?id=uBpDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA455&lpg=PA455&dq=%22Haro!%22+obscure+shout&source=bl&ots=b1_Q81PRA5&sig=b9BuaWRy1wGyM9cWHot1WnNCaE0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJo5_Zq-fOAhWI6CYKHY0XBMwQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Haro!%22%20obscure%20shout&f=false)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Or [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/10230009).

Comment: @snailplane From what I've seen, the names of non-existent things are the _only_ ones on which the factions might agree.

Comment: @StoneyB It just occurred to me that we can start with Thurber's "the thinger for the thing contained."

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of attempting to standardize our vocabulary, we should simply point out when we think something should be clarified for the benefit of the reader.

The community changes continuously with new folks coming in and old timers taking breaks. Instead of having to on-board newcomers, we should just engage with each other and maybe have a few documented but general "best practices".